# Performance, check if value exists array or query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I need to check if a value exists in my database

I have a table where every user has an unique code. For example: 5h27f.

These values and users add up very quickly. So very soon I might have +2000 unique codes. What's the best, fastest and most efficient way to check if a value is unique?

```
foreach ($users as $user) {

    $is_unique = FALSE;

    while ($is_unique == FALSE) {
        $code = unique_code();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM unique_code_table WHERE code='$code';";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0 {
        } else {
            $is_unique = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
$query = "SELECT code FROM unique_code_table;";
$res = mysqli->query($query);

$codes = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $codes[$i] = $row->code;
    $i++;
}

$code = unique_code();
while (in_array($code, $codes) {
    $code = unique_code();
}
```

*(this code might not be 100% accurate, I've written this just to explain the purpose of the question.)*

Comment: Why do you need to check?

Comment: @Strawberry because I want to create an unique download link for every user, for every piece of content. For example, I want to send a .pdf file to all my contacts. I'd like to know how many people click etc. And I want a random strings, so they can't 'guess' the code of someone else.

Comment: Would you be prepared to use a string like this instead? SV50ey57XE6cBy6gDe9q0g

Comment: @Strawberry I use the first 8 characters of a md5() hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that one query trip to the database vs. potentially 2000+ is significantly better to do. Second script will be significantly faster.

On the first code a `LIMIT 1` would do wonders but compared to the second query it will pale as far as benchmarks are concerned.

Put the following at the bottom of your script to fine tune and benchmark:
PHP 5.4 +

```
$sParseTime = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
echo $sParseTime;
```